# PostgreSQL custom C function import fails: "sprintf_chk: symbol not found"

Tags: c, postgresql, stdio

I want to use the functions from the stdio.h library to manipulate some strings in a PostgreSQL C function. Problem: for some reason, when I try to import it in the database with `CREATE EXTENSION` it fails and returns:
`ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/test.so": Error relocating /usr/local/lib/postgresql/test.so: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found`.
Here is the test function I use:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "executor/executor.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(printTest);
Datum printTest(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    char str[50];
    int i = 9;
    sprintf(str, "Hello I am PostgreSQL %d ! \n", i);
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text(str));
}
```

And here is my Makefile:

```
PG_CPPFLAGS = -I$(/usr/include)
SHLIB_LINK = $(stdio.h)

EXTENSION = test
DATA = test--0.1.sql
MODULE_big = test
OBJS = test.o

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 inside a docker container.

I already had a problem like this one with another library and the solution was to change the makefile. I tried to do it also this time, but it does not work and I don't know what else to change.

If you know what may be causing the problem, you are very welcome.

I you know the name of a book or website that offers a good documentation on how to write C functions for Postgres, you are even more welcome. I am constantly running into this kind of stupid problems because the official documentation is too weak.

Comment: The `__sprintf_chk()` function is used by some systems when you call `sprintf()` via a macro in `<stdio.h>`.  It would normally be in the C library.  If it shows up missing, it suggests that the compilation was done in an environment incompatible with where you're running it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine, except that you forgot the line

```
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
```

towards the beginning.

There must be a problem with the way you are building the shared object.

Correct would be:

```
PATH=/where/your/postgres/is/bin:$PATH make
```

For more information please share your extension SQL script, the control file and your exact build process.